# Text domain in php code

Tags: wordpress, translation

I have the following code in my WordPress theme:

```
$to_return .= '<th><label for="user_login">Username</label></th>';
```

How can I use the text domain to translate the word Username? 
I tried

```
$to_return .= '<th><label for="user_login"><?php _e("Username", "mytheme"); ?></label></th>';
```

but no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2):

```
$to_return .= '<th><label for="user_login">' . __("Username", "mytheme") . '</label></th>';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to specify `<?php` and `?>` when you're already in PHP.

To concatenate a function's return value within a string, use the `.` operator.

Also, as @RRikesh points, `_e` should read `__`, since `_e` echoes and `__` returns:

```
$to_return .= '<th><label for="user_login">' . __("Username", "mytheme") . '</label></th>';
```

Comment: I get no errors but the text Username don't show up on frontend where is supposed to be.

Comment: I guess `_e` should have been `__` instead.

Comment: `_e` echoes the value, while `__` returns it.